# Excel:Increase value of a cell by 15 minutes for every cell that contains a value higher than 0)

Tags: excel

I have to Increase value of a cell by 15 minutes for every cell on the same row with a value higher than 0.

Comment: You can do this with a formula in a different cell that references the base value.  Or you can do it with vba to use the actual cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner I understand that I need to use a formula,I presume some sort of IF statement but I don't know how to do it in excel,I know where to write it I would like to write something like  if(cell is between A-X &&cell.value>0) increase time by 15 minutes

Comment: `=B1 + (COUNTIFS(A1:A15,">=1",A1:A15,"<=15") * Time(0,15,0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner So I found what I needed exactly with the help of your formula but I'm getting  #VALUE instead of a real value I'm using =TIME(0;0;0)+(IF(D13:BG13;">0")*TIME(0;15;0))   I have tried changing this :(TIME(0;0;0)) to the cell where I want to get the sum but I get a circular reference error? and if I try to put 0:0:0 in a cell and use that I get  #VALUE again , any clue?Thanks for the help up to now.

Comment: the issue is this part `(IF(D13:BG13;">0")` you can't do that.  Use the countif.